# How do I make a box that i can move. I am new to wxwidgets and wondering if there is a way to move a box

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

The Image is what I currently have made, I plan to make an Elevator that can go up and down. I am unsure of how I would move a box such that it stays at the same x cords but changes the y cords. Any help is appreciated.

This is for a project I am doing. The specifications state

```
 "In this project, the group is required to 
develop  a  programme  that  simulates  the  operation  of  arrays  (columns)  of  elevators 
running over a multi‐storey building. The program  (application) should be able  to cope 
with user defined number of elevators and number of storeys along with an ability for a 
user to simulate or represent elevator passengers making request for elevator service to 
particular  floors. The program  should have a user interface  that displays  the elevators’ 
states  allows  user  input  and  ideally  shows  (simulates)  the  vertical  movement  of  each 
elevator. "
```

[Simulation Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnte7.png)

I am looking for something that will move the "Elevator A" box with the buttons up or down, along with a box inside the elevator shaft, both move up and down in unison. The code should do this automatically hopefully without having to drag the boxes and buttons with a mouse.

cMain.hpp (Updated)

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _cMain_
#define _cMain_
#include <wx/frame.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>
class cMain : public wxFrame {
public:
    cMain(wxWindow* parent,
        wxWindowID id,
        const wxString& title,
        const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
        const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
        long style = wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,
        const wxString& name = wxASCII_STR(wxFrameNameStr));
    ~cMain();
    wxStaticBox* m_box1 = nullptr;
    wxStaticBox* m_box2 = nullptr;
    wxStaticBox* m_box3 = nullptr;
    wxButton* m_btng = nullptr;
    wxButton* m_btn1 = nullptr;
    wxButton* m_btn2 = nullptr;
    wxButton* m_btn3 = nullptr;
    wxButton* m_btn_up = nullptr;
    wxButton* m_btn_down = nullptr;
    wxListBox* m_list1 = nullptr;
    void Ground_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    void Level_1_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    void Level_2_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    void Level_3_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    void Call_Up_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    void Call_Down_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

#endif /* */
```

cMain.cpp (Updated)

```
#include "cMain.h"
#include "id.h"
#include <wx/dc.h>
#include <wx/graphics.h>
#include <wx/dcbuffer.h>
#include <wx/event.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "cElevator.h"
using namespace std;
cElevator e;
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(cMain, wxFrame)

wxEND_EVENT_TABLE();
cMain::cMain(wxWindow* parent,
wxWindowID id,
const wxString& title,
const wxPoint& pos,
const wxSize& size,
long style ,
const wxString& name) : wxFrame(parent,id,title,pos,size,style,name)
{   
    this->SetBackgroundColour(*wxWHITE);
    m_box1 = new wxStaticBox(this, wxID_ANY, "Call 1", wxPoint(252, 530), wxSize(50, 80));
    m_btn_up = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "/\\", wxPoint(265, 547), wxSize(25, 25));
    m_btn_down = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "\\/", wxPoint(265, 575), wxSize(25, 25));

    //Inner Panel
    m_box2 = new wxStaticBox(this, wxID_ANY, "Elevator A", wxPoint(164, 530), wxSize(80, 80));

    m_btng = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, wxString("G"), wxPoint(177, 575), wxSize(25, 25));
    m_btn1 = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, wxString("1"), wxPoint(177, 547), wxSize(25, 25));
    m_btn2 = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, wxString("2"), wxPoint(207, 575), wxSize(25, 25));
    m_btn3 = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, wxString("3"), wxPoint(207, 547), wxSize(25, 25));

    //Elevator Shafts
    //m_box3 = new wxStaticBox(panel, wxID_ANY, "", wxPoint(80, 10), wxSize(80, 600));

    //Other 
    m_list1 = new wxListBox(this, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(200, 10), wxSize(100, 100));
    m_btn_up->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &cMain::Call_Up_Button, this);
    m_btn_down->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &cMain::Call_Down_Button, this);
    m_btng->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &cMain::Ground_Button, this);
    m_btn1->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &cMain::Level_1_Button, this);
    m_btn2->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &cMain::Level_2_Button, this);
    m_btn3->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &cMain::Level_3_Button, this);
}
void cMain::Ground_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    e.GLevel = true;
    
    m_list1->AppendString("Going to Ground Level");
    evt.Skip();

}
void cMain::Level_1_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    
    m_list1->AppendString("Going to Level 1");
    evt.Skip();
}
void cMain::Level_2_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    
    m_list1->AppendString("Going to Level 2");
    evt.Skip();
}
void cMain::Level_3_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    
    m_list1->AppendString("Going to Level 3");
    evt.Skip();
}
void cMain::Call_Up_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    
    m_list1->AppendString("Going to Up");
    //evt.Skip();
}
void cMain::Call_Down_Button(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    
    m_list1->AppendString("Going Down");
    //evt.Skip();
}

cMain::~cMain() {

}
```

cElevator.hpp

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class cElevator : public wxFrame
{
public:
    cElevator(wxWindow* parent,
        wxWindowID id,
        const wxString& title,
        const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
        const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
        long style = wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,
        const wxString& name = wxASCII_STR(wxFrameNameStr));
    ~cElevator();

    bool GLevel;
    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& evt);


    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
```

cElevator.cpp

```
#include "cMain.h"
#include "cElevator.h"
#include <wx/dc.h>
#include <wx/graphics.h>
#include <wx/dcbuffer.h>
#include <wx/event.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(cElevator,wxPanel)
EVT_PAINT(cElevator::OnPaint)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE();

cElevator::cElevator(wxWindow* parent,
    wxWindowID id,
    const wxString& title,
    const wxPoint& pos,
    const wxSize& size,
    long style,
    const wxString& name) : wxFrame(parent,id,title,pos,size,style,name)
{
    this->SetBackgroundColour(*wxBLACK);

}

void cElevator::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& evt)
{
    wxClientDC cdc(this);
    wxBufferedDC dc(&cdc);
    wxGraphicsContext* gc = wxGraphicsContext::Create(dc);


    // make a path that contains a circle and some lines
    gc->SetPen(*wxWHITE_PEN);
    wxGraphicsPath path = gc->CreatePath();
    path.CloseSubpath();
    path.AddRectangle(80.0, 10.0, 80.0, 800.0);
    path.MoveToPoint(80, 600);
    path.AddLineToPoint(160, 600);
    path.MoveToPoint(80, 400);
    path.AddLineToPoint(160, 400);
    path.MoveToPoint(80, 200);
    path.AddLineToPoint(160, 200);
    //path.AddRectangle(90, 740, 60, 65);
    //path.AddRectangle(90, 530, 60, 65);
    //path.AddRectangle(90, 330, 60, 65);
    //path.AddRectangle(90, 130, 60, 65);
    gc->StrokePath(path);

    delete gc;
}

cElevator::~cElevator() {

}
```

Paintting part

```
void cElevator::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& evt)
{
    int CurrentPosy = 130;
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    dc.DrawRectangle(80.0, 10.0, 80.0, 800.0);//overall rectangle for  elevator shaft
    dc.Clear();
    dc.SetPen(*wxWHITE);
    dc.SetBrush(*wxLIGHT_GREY_BRUSH);
    while (CurrentPosy != ExpectedPosy)
    {
        dc.DrawRectangle(90, CurrentPosy, 60, 65);
            //CurrentPosy--; // or currentPOs.y++;
        wxSleep(5);
        dc.Clear();
    }
    dc.SetPen(wxNullPen);
    dc.SetBrush(wxNullBrush);
```

The ExpectedPosy is in the header file as an int, that should get a value when the ground button (or other level buttons) is pressed.

Comment: you could try to create an animation gif file and use it. Take a look at the `animate` sample for details. Or you are talking about dragging this up/down with the mouse? Also, please retain of posting the links to external sources on SO - post the code you have inline and explain clearly what you are looking for to achieve.

Comment: Please, post text as text instead of images of text.

Comment: Hopefully this helps!!

Comment: @Hamid, I also see you are using the absolute positioning/sizing. Please avoid that and try to use sizers. If you move you program to a different OS or a different screen resolution or change a theme the layout you were trying to make will be broken. On top of that the fiont might become blurry on HighDPI display.

Comment: I added a little bit of context near the beginning. I didn't state it is for a project, I have added in the specifications needed to be satisfied. Maybe this can help with anything.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you will have some kind of box drawn inside the elevator shaft and then this shaft will be equally divided by 5.

Now what you do is following:

You keep the vector of positions for each floor. You can get it if you call `GetSize()` on the elevator box and divide the height by 5.

Next you will have an initial position of the shaft at (0,0), which will be your current position.

You will need to catch the EVT_PAINT() messqage of the elevator shaft.

When the user press the button you will calculate the new position and set the flag to repaint the shaft.

In the handler you will need to create a wxPaintDC object (not a pointer), then do:

```
dc.Clear();
dc.SetPen();
dc.SetBrush();
while( currentPos.y != expectedPos.y )
{
    dc.DrawLine();
    dc.DrawLIne();
    dc.DrawLine();
    dc.DrawLione();
    currentPos.y--; // or currentPOs.y++;
    wxSleep( 5 );
    dc.Clear();
}
dc.SetPen( wxNullPen );
dc.SetBrush( wxNullBrush );
```

or something to that extent.

But I hope you get the idea.

Let us know if that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Will you be able to show me exactly what you mean above if you don't mind?

Comment: Im really unsure where things are supposed to be

Comment: Instead of removing the entire shaft can the box move alone allong with Elevator A panel?

Comment: @Hamid, I basically wrote an algorithm for you. all you need to do is to paint the actual elevator inside the `EVT_PAINT` and check the appropriate flag in there. And I'm sorry - I don't have time to write a fully functional code for you. You need to learn the language (C++) first and then try to use such an advanced library as wxWidgets. Good luck.

Comment: Is currentpos.y and expectedpos.y variables such as an int?

Comment: @Hamid, yes, they are as positions are usually an integers. But you can make them double easily, because you don't know the size of tjhe shaft/the height of the floor in advance. And of course you will have to experiment with the steps of increase/decrease the coordinate in order to make an animation smooth.

Comment: Seem to only draw when using wxGraphicContext stuff but not with whats above

Comment: @hamid, can you post an exact code using my template?

Comment: I would but the thing is the actual shapes paned get pained behind the main wxFrame

Comment: @Hamid, can you post the code and how do you catch the paint event?

Comment: Updated it, Turns out I have to have to Panels since having them in one is a bit problematic with the paint layer under the main layer.

Comment: Just a matter of getting it so it make the rectangular box in the elevator shaft and be able to move. I can understande where the ExpectedPosY is coming from but not sure how to get the CurrentPosY?

Comment: And to make it so that a user can define Number of floors, number of elevators too

Comment: @Hamid, its easy - `CurrentPos` in the beginning is (0,0). Then the Y value will increase/decrease.

Comment: So how do i bind it to a button click?

Comment: I have tried adding in the code you presented above, but it just freezes the windows

Comment: @Hamid, please post the code you tried. Just edit your original post.

Comment: Added it in, i changed the drawline to draw rectangle

Comment: @Hamid, you have 2 paint event handlers. The second one is correct. Are you saying it doesn't work? You also need to uncomment `CurrentPosY--` line or `CurrentPosY++` depending whether the elevator is going up or down.

Comment: Also - keep in mind that those cooredinates (and layout) will be screwed when you move to the HighDPI screen or use another system/theme/font etc. It is better to use sizers and get the position/size in the constructor/paint event handler.